# rcpp_hello_world. undefined reference

Tags: eclipse, rinside

I have a problem in building the basic example rcpp_hello_world.
I have followed the example referred at 
http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170

It is all ok up to the linking, when I find the following error

```
Building target: MyCppPackage_4
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/R/lib64/R/lib -o "MyCppPackage_4"  ./src/RcppExports.o ./src/main.o ./src/rcpp_hello_world.o  /usr/local/R/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so /usr/local/R/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib/libRInside.so -lR -lRblas
./src/main.o: In function `main':
/home/luigi/workspace-mars/MyCppPackage_4/Debug/../src/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `rcpp_hello_world'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MyCppPackage_4] Error 1
```

here the code of the main.cpp file

```cpp
/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 13, 2016
 *      Author: luigi
 */

#ifdef INSIDE

#include <Rcpp.h>

#include <RInside.h>    // for the embedded R via RInside
#include "rcpp_hello_world.h"

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

//RcppExport SEXP rcpp_hello_world();
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance

    SEXP s = rcpp_hello_world();

    Language call("print",s);

    call.eval();
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

I'm sorry for disordered post
I'm thankful for any hint

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have the wrong tag. It is an `rinside` question, not an `rcpp` question.

Next, for `rinside`, we have eight (yes, 8) directories with working example.  Change directory into `examples/standard/` and say `make`.  Well over a dozen examples will build.

These serve as a reference, and a **working** build environment.  If you choose to ignore these as help, your build may fail.  Which is why we give you a (tested !!) environment in which it will work.

Comment: I'm thankful for Your promptness and I'm following Your hint